# Call to undefined method PDF::Code128()

Tags: methods, undefined, fpdf

Edited:
I try to use "Code 128 barcodes" (from a class in this page [fpdf.org](http://fpdf.org) (fpdf.org->scripts->Code 128 barcodes).
The method Code128() is inside "class PDF_Code128 extends FPDF" in "code128.php"
I have this error "Call to undefined method FPDF::Code128()" when I call Code128 which is a method of the class PDF_Code128()
This is an example

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
require('code128.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$code='ABCDEFG1234567890AbCdEf';
$pdf->Code128(50,170,$code,125,20);//<--Call to undefined method FPDF::Code128()
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(33,239);
$pdf->Write(1,'Some text');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

If barcode object is created with $pdf = new PDF_Code128(); the barcode is working, and the $pdf object have acces to the parent methods like SetXY() and Write(), but if created with $pdf = new FPDF(); the parent can´t use the childs methods like Code128()?

Here is an example of what I want:

```
$obj = new PDF_Code128();
$code='0123456789';
$obj->Code128(45,280,$code,125,10);

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
--here I want to add $obj to $pdf, or just call Code128() without creating $obj if possible--
--kind of obj1->addChild(obj2)---
$pdf->Output();
```

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Where does the `PDF` class come from? As far as I can see in the source file only `FPDF` exists? That said, `PDF_Code128` already extends the `FPDF` class, so it should work fine if you just switch to that?

Comment: I used PDF in the place of FPDF when I added other class before, now I writed new short code, I copied again all from the website, I used '$pdf = new FPDF();' but I dosen´t help, it works only if I did '$pdf = new PDF_Code128();' as showen in the example there.

Comment: Since `PDF_Code128` extends `FPDF`, it's the same class but with some methods added. When you call `PDF_Code128->AddPage()` it checks to see if `PDF_Code128` has a `AddPage` method, and since it doesn't it asks the parent if it has a `AddPage` method, which it does, so it uses that instead.

Comment: Yes this is how it should be but there is something I don´t know what makes fpdf class with '$pdf = new FPDF();'  not working with other classes. 
for example the calss rotations from scripts from the same page[fpdf.org] 
'$pdf = new FPDF();' dosen´t work but '$pdf = new PDF();' works!??

Comment: What class rotation? `new PDF_Code128()` works fine.

Comment: strange!
is this code working?

    <?php
    require('fpdf.php');
    require('code128.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();'
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
    $code='0123456789';
    $pdf->Code128(45,280,$code,125,10);
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>

Comment: No, because `FPDF` doesn't have a `Code128` function. `$pdf = new PDF_Code128();` would work though.

Comment: Yes it works but again when I add rotations what works only with '$pdf = new PDF();' the same problem again, Call to undefined method PDF_Code128::RotatedText()
because PDF_Code128 dosen´t have RotateText() method...
so how can I use both calsses with fpdf?
I mean how can I use barcode and rotate text in the same pdf?

Comment: Then I'll aks again: where is `PDF` from? It's not in the regular `FPDF` package.

Comment: I used FPDF first, but when I added rotations to my code it dosen´t work, so I used as given in the example PDF in the place of FPDF, and everything works fine, you can see online that example from ->[fpdf.org]->scripts->rotations there is a link to test the script

Comment: Simply change `class PDF_Code128 extends FPDF` to `class PDF_Code128 extends PDF`.

Comment: I tried that before but not working, it´s just because PDF is nowhere, I don´t know how it works for fpdf and with rotation, but not with code128, this is the error when I replaced class PDF_Code128 extends FPDF to class PDF_Code128 extends PDF  ## Fatal error: Class 'PDF' not found in ##

Comment: Do you load the file which it's in? Usually using `include` or `require`. You need all the classes available.

Comment: yes in the begining of the file
    require('fpdf.php');
    require('code128.php');
    require('rotation.php');

Comment: You haven't included `rotation` by the time you include `code128` hence it doesn't know that the PDF class is inside `rotation.php`. Always include parents first. First include `fpdf`, then `rotation` and finally the upper most child (`code128`).

Comment: I changed the order but it doesn´t help

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks you h2ooooooo for your efforts and help! Thanks for stackoverflow.com where I found the most of my questions already answered and ready)
Solution:

in the file rotation.php class PDF_Rotate extends PDF_Code128 (and not extends FPDF!!)

Child2(class rotation)>extends>Child1(class code128)>extends>Parent(class FPDF)

When Child2 is created, the parents (Child1 and Parent) methods are available for it.
it´s all, my question was maybe not clear.

Here is the final code using FPDF, Code128 and Rotation classes together:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
require('code128.php');//<--This must be called before rotation.php (because rotation     extends code128 class)
require('rotation.php');

class PDF extends PDF_Rotate
{
 function RotatedText($x,$y,$txt,$angle)
  {
  //Text rotated around its origin
  $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
  $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
  $this->Rotate(0);
  }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
$code='0123456789';
$pdf->Code128(13,15,$code,125,10);
$pdf->RotatedText(10,30,'Vertical Text',90);
$pdf->Write(1,'text test');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```